# Powershell: Get the last digit from a random array of numbers

Tags: powershell

Im currently accessing an API and parsing an XML sheet to get the computer IDs off of 3000+ systems. Im getting the IDs and storing them in the var $computers, and I need the last digit *ONLY* so I can use a switch to get them into the proper group. Here's what I have;

```
foreach($ID in $Computers){

Switch ($ID){

    0{write-host "0"}
    1{write-host "1"}
    2{write-host "2"}
    3{write-host "3"}
    4{write-host "4"}
    5{write-host "5"}
    6{write-host "6"}
    7{write-host "7"}
    8{write-host "8"}
    9{write-host "9"}


}
```

}

I redacted the actual commands in the {} due to privacy (I am using a company specific URL). The ID numbers come in formats like this "1" or "11" all the way to "1111". Basically, one line of numbers, maxing at 4 numbers. All random, and in no seemingly particular order. I've been googling this for hours and cant come up with anything on how to get it to grab the last number from the ID. Any help would be HUGELY appreciated.

Comment: Mathematically, you could modulo 10 to get the last digit only. `$ID % 10` should work in powershell

Comment: I just gave that a shot, it says "[System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Modulus'."

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: `[-1]` takes the last character from a string.

```
$computers = '111', '23', '1567'

foreach ($ID in $computers) {   

    switch ($ID[-1]) {

       0 { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "0" }
       1 { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "1" }
       2 { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "2" }
       3 { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "3" }
       4 { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "4" }
       5 { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "5" }
       6 { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "6" }
       7 { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "7" }
       8 { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "8" }
       9 { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "9" }
    }
}
```

Either you spent hours Googling and didn't find that -> *you desperately need a PowerShell in a Month of Lunches type book, or tutorial*.

Or, you have some weird format IDs where that won't do. Regex is fun, another approach might be:

```
$computers = '111', '23', '1567'

switch -regex ($computers) {

   '.*0$' { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "0" }
   '.*1$' { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "1" }
   '.*2$' { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "2" }
   '.*3$' { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "3" }
   '.*4$' { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "4" }
   '.*5$' { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "5" }
   '.*6$' { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "6" }
   '.*7$' { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "7" }
   '.*8$' { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "8" }
   '.*9$' { write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "9" }

}
```

example output:

[image: Screenshot of example code's output]

Switch statements will loop over arrays implicitly, adjust regex to fit ID format.

Comment: You can remove `.*` part from your regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me, per Eris's comment. The issue, which I failed to mention and understand myself, was that the XML I was storing in the $ID var didn't have the data I needed as is. I needed to parse it as $ID.id to get the ID element from the XML. So my bad everyone!!

```
foreach($ID in $Computers){
$Lastdigit = $ID.id % 10
Switch ($Lastdigit){

0{write-host "0"}
1{write-host "1"}
2{write-host "2"}
3{write-host "3"}
4{write-host "4"}
5{write-host "5"}
6{write-host "6"}
7{write-host "7"}
8{write-host "8"}
9{write-host "9"}
```

}